# When was (and in what paper) Paley-Wiener integral invented?

Tags: mathematics, probability

When was (and in what paper) Paley-Wiener integral invented?

Also, what was first? Paley-Wiener integral or Multiple Wiener Integral?

Comment: What's Paley-Wiener integral?

Answer (score 1):

Notes on the theory and application of Fourier transforms (with
R. E. A. C. Paley) Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 35 (1933) 348-355 and 761-791.